# Is it possible to have multiple gather environments in one line?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, layout, tags, gather

Specifically, I want to arrange many small equations in a more compact manner, but still include a `\tag` with each one. Currently, I typeset the longer equations like this:

```tex
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
 \section{Equations}
 \begin{gather*}
  \tag{A}
  v_1 = v_2
   = v_3 \\
  \qquad = v_4 v_5
 \end{gather*}
 \begin{gather*}
  \tag{B}
  ax^5 + bx^4
   + cx^3 + \cdots \\
  \qquad = f(a, b, c, \dots)
 \end{gather*}
 et cetera
\end{document}
```

producing something like this:
[image: Result of the previous LaTeX code]

However, when writing shorter equations (the previous code doesn't match the paper size and equation length I work with), I want to arrange these equations in sequence and not necessarily on individual lines.

How can I achieve this while maintaining the existing look/structure, or is `gather*` simply unsuited for this? What should I do?

Comment: You should be able to use `gather` with `gathered` groupings nested inside.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear. If If you like to have short, multiline equations in paralel, than you can enclose them in paralel `minipage`s or write in table, as is done in MWE (Minimal Working Example) below. In it is considered @Barbara Beeton  comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,      % in real document delete this option
            a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\fleqn}X<{\endfleqn}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{-1ex}%
}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Equations}
\lipsum[1][1-2]\par
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} M{0.8}M{1.2} @{}}
\begin{equation} 
    \begin{gathered}
  v_1 = v_2 = v_3 \\ 
    = v_4 v_5
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
    & 
\begin{equation} 
    \begin{gathered}
  ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + \cdots \\
   = f(a, b, c, \dots)
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}\\
\lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines indicate text borders)

*Note*: above proposed solution works fine, if equations are short. At longer you need to write on usual way, i.e. inserted directly in a text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `minipage` environment is what you need:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
 \begin{gather*}
  \tag{A}
  v_1 = v_2
   = v_3 \\
  \qquad = v_4 v_5
 \end{gather*}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
 \begin{gather*}
  \tag{B}
  ax^5 + bx^4
   + cx^3 + \cdots \\
  \qquad = f(a, b, c, \dots)
 \end{gather*}
 \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3wng.jpg]